# Where can I find a good source for  standard decks in Magic: The Gathering?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am just getting back into Magic: The Gathering, and I see a lot of people talking about specific decks, like **CawBlade**. So my question is two fold, is there someplace that lists what cards make up these specific decks, and are these specific decks always the same (does every CawBlade deck have the same cards) or are they just similar decks with the same theme?

Maybe this is two questions . . .

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of these decks have been created for competitions and are competition winners.

To find decks by name:

[mtgvault](http://www.mtgvault.com/DeckSearch.aspx)

[moxdiamond](http://www.moxdiamond.com/Decks.html)

[competitions decks](http://www.channelfireball.com/category/decklists/)

and a lot more...

As you will see when searching for specific decks, your second question will answer itself.
Most specific decks originate from competition play and have been winners or performed well at some point. So originally they had a fixed list of cards but when they became public many people improved them with other cards. So you will find the official cawblade that won competition x as well as other improved versions from anonymous players with some different cards but the main strategy doesn't change and is based around the same few cards.

Answer (score 8):

The best idea is to check out a few sites that are dedicated to the game. Most of them have a collections of Pro players that write for the sites, which gives a lot of insight if you are into reading about the game.

Some other sites provide a resource for viewing decks, seeing what decks work, and also seeing the decklists for decks that have done well at big tournaments.

http://magic.tcgplayer.com/

http://starcitygames.com/

http://www.channelfireball.com/

There are plenty more, but check out these three to start.

Answer (score 6):

All the sites abovementioned are very good - but you could also go straight to the official site:

http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/Events.aspx?x=mtg/daily/eventcoverage/decklists

Wizards of the Coast's coverage of its own products is not *always* the most unbiased, but you can't really go wrong with all these successful decklists from events around the world...